# Dual boot advice, should I copy win files?

Tags: multi-boot, file-management

So I was using windows 7 on my computer and recently installed linux. Now windows is in c: partition and debian (linux) is in another partition. I'm interested in seeing the c: files from debian. And in fact I can! But they appear as inside a external drive, or another drive outside of linux root's drive. This doesn't surprise me. But are this files going to be treated normally, for example, are there going to be in searches? The only importanta are documents, and they are in very specific folders of c: .should i tell linux something to treat this as a normal hard drive? For example changing some atributes of it. Ot should i copy it's content into root (seems a waste of space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to automatically mount your Windows partition on startup, and to create shortcuts to your Windows directories from you Linux partition.

For example, under `/home/user/documents` you could add a shortcut to your "My Documents" directory (that's the solution I use). From there, you can search and Linux will treat the link as a sub-folder of `/home/user/documents`.

In my opinion, it's the best way to seamlessly integrate the your separate partitions. One limiting factor is files 'deleted' on your Windows partition will be permanently deleted instead of being moved to your recycle bin. Otherwise, the files are treated the same.